# Can I use TS classes/interfaces in a simple JS mean application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mean-stack

Let's say that I have a build up MEAN application written in JS, and I want to keep it but add some classes/interfaces using TS (I want to do this because I want interfaces) and use it in my controllers to communicate with my backend. Is it possible? If yes, how do i do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Classes are something very different from interfaces. Which of them do you actually want?

Comment: Hi @Bergi, actually I want to use inheritance in my classes, and use interfaces to simplify my modeling... also I would like to use interfaces as a object type, if possible

Comment: TypeScript interfaces are no tangible values at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since TypeScript is a superset of javascript all JS code will work in typescript BUT you need to change the file extensions from .js to .ts

Furthermore, all typescript code must be compiled back to javascript before run. which means a typescript compiler has to be installed and configured.

That was my answer to your question.

As a piece of advice since you are building with MEAN stack then you are used to Angular way of structuring code.

If that is the case then you can build your server the same way with TypeScript using a framework called NestJS which is very very similar to Angular:

https://nestjs.com

Comment: Hi Mohamed Aljamil, thanks for your answer! You mean I could just configure a compiler in my project, use TS classes and then make reference to the transpiled files in my JS code and then use as normal classes? Also, tks for the nestJS idea, but I could use TS with MEAN too, just didn't want to start all over again....

Comment: What you just mentioned can be done as well but it would be a dev hell (for me anyway) i like my projects to be all the same either all JS or all TS. But that is up to you.